# gulp-zip omits hidden files

Tags: gulp, gulp-zip

I've created a Gulp task to export my Subversion working copy and then ZIP it. Hidden (dot) files like `.htaccess` are present in the exported directory but not in the ZIP. What am I missing?

Here's the relevant code:

```
var codigoProjecto = "foo";
var dirSalida = "./Servidor/archivos/tmp";

gulp.task('zip', function() {
    var temp = require('temp');
    var path = require('path');
    var child_process = require('child_process');
    var zip = require('gulp-zip');

    var revision, nombreBase, dirExport;

    temp.track();

    revision = child_process.execFileSync('svn', [
        'info',
        '--show-item=last-changed-revision',
        '--no-newline'
    ]);
    revision = parseInt(revision, 10);

    nombreBase = codigoProjecto + " " + (new Date()).toISOString().slice(0,10) + ' r' + revision;
    dirExport = path.join(temp.mkdirSync(codigoProjecto + "-"), nombreBase);

    gutil.log('Exportando copia de trabajo...');
    child_process.execFileSync('svn', [
        'export',
        '--quiet',
        '-r', 'COMMITTED',
        '.',
        dirExport
    ]);
    gutil.log('Empaquetando código...');
    gulp.src([
        path.normalize(dirExport + '/..') + '/**',
        '!' + dirExport + '/doc{,/**}',
        '!' + dirExport + '/node_modules{,/**}',
        '!' + dirExport + '/psd{,/**}',
        '!' + dirExport + '/scripts-utiles{,/**}',
        '!' + dirExport + '/*.txt',
        '!' + dirExport + '/.htaccess',
        '!' + dirExport + '/gulpfile.js',
        '!' + dirExport + '/package.json'
    ])
        .pipe(zip(nombreBase + '.zip'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dirSalida));

    gutil.log("Salida: %s", gutil.colors.green.bold(path.resolve(dirSalida + '/' + nombreBase + '.zip')));
});
```

Comment: try adding `dirExport + '/.*''` to the path

Comment: Just tried all combinations I've been able to think of. I'm afraid I only managed to copy the top level hidden file... onto a wrong location! Thanks anyway for the hint, my problem must have to do with the magnificence of globstarred paths.

Comment: for that you can just do `dirExport + './**/.*'`, it will add inner hidden files as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[gulp.src()](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/v3.9.1/docs/API.md#gulpsrcglobs-options) accepts a [second argument](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/v3.9.1/docs/API.md#options) that's used to pass options to the underlying component, [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob):

> Type: `Object`
>
> Options to pass to node-glob through glob-stream.
>
> gulp supports all options supported by node-glob and glob-stream
>   except ignore and adds the following options.

Right there [was the answer](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/tree/v7.0.0#dots):

> You can make glob treat dots as normal characters by setting `dot:true`
>   in the options.

So voilá:

```
gulp.src([
    path.normalize(dirExport + '/..') + '/**',
    '!' + dirExport + '/doc{,/**}',
    // ....
    '!' + dirExport + '/package.json'
], {
    dot: true
})
```

*In theory, it should be possible to compose path globs that include dot files explicitly but the syntax is rather counter-intuitive and: 1) I couldn't find how to do it globally (i.e. for all subdirectories) 2) I got scary unexpected results, such as `.htaccess` files moving from their location to base directory*